# Can SQL profiles be deployed to other Oracle Databases?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, tuning

When using The SQL Tuning Advisor in SQL-Developer. I get often some recommendations to accept a SQL-Profil. I guess it is a good idea to do so.

But is this similar to proposed indexes, which I can deploy to similar databases or is this something, that must be analyzed for each individual database?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Profiles are basically a kind of statistics rather than a database object like an index, but they can be transported to another database - see [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/11607/export-sql-tuning-profile-to-another-instance) for how